# redirection of login form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using `wp_login_form()` on a site at the moment, and when you log in correctly it redirects the user to the appropriate URL.

Unfortunately if you make a mistake in the username/password it forwards you to `wp-login.php`, which shakes its box at the user. And disrupts consistent brand experience, like.

So does anybody know a way to make it not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

This will let you include the header and footer of the theme at login page

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'wp_custom_login_header' );
    function wp_custom_login_header() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-custom-login' );

        do_action('wp_custom_login_header_before');
        get_header();
        do_action('wp_custom_login_header_after');
    }

    add_action( 'login_footer', 'wp_custom_login_footer' );
    function wp_custom_login_footer() {
        do_action('wp_custom_login_footer_before');
        get_footer();
        do_action('wp_custom_login_footer_after');
    }

    function wp_custom_login_is_login_page() {
        return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By saying you use the `wp_login_form()` function, I'm guessing you use a custom form on its own page.

There are a couple of things you can do.

If this form is on it's own page and you just want the incorrect password/username to go back to that page and alert the user, you can create a function in your `functions.php` file which will do a redirect to the referring page like so:

```php
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );  // hook failed login

function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
   $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
   // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
   if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
      wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
      exit;
   }
}
```

---

If you just want to remove the shake, you can use this piece of code in your `functions.php` file which will stop the shake.

```php
function my_login_head() {
remove_action('login_head', 'wp_shake_js', 12);
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_login_head');
```

---

This last suggestion is just based on a user accessing the `wp-login.php` page and then kicking them back to your custom login page.

```php
function redirect_login_page() {
    $login_page  = home_url( '/login/' ); // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PAGE URL
    $page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
        wp_redirect($login_page);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init','redirect_login_page');
```

Comment: its doesn't work.  i have a wordpress theme and which is already contain all code for login/signup but when i'm entering wrong password and blank fields then its redirect to wp-login.php page other wise when all fields are filled than its working.

Comment: Which piece of code did you try? the top or the bottom?

Comment: top   add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );  // hook failed login

function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
   $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
   // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
   if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
      wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
      exit;
   }
}

Comment: and you've added this to your `functions.php` file?

Comment: yeah, i added it but its not working now. i have to add both top and bottom code in function.php file.

Comment: please suggest me if any other solution u have.

Comment: @NeerajMishra see my new option at the bottom of the answer. Should hopefully work for you without a problem.